# How to make first items wrap on top of other items using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making some radiobuttons. It's almost how i want it.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

label {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  color: White;
  background: dimgrey;
  
  &:hover {
    color: White;
    background: dimgrey;
  }
}

input[type=radio] + label:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

label + input[type=radio] + label {
  border-left: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.radio-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: max-content;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 0.5px solid dimgrey;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="radio-group flexbox">
    <input type="radio" id="alle" value="alle" name="selector" checked><label for="alle">Alle</label
    ><input type="radio" id="aktiv" value="aktiv" name="selector" ><label for="aktiv">Aktive</label
    ><input type="radio" id="inaktiv" value="inaktiv" name="selector"><label for="inaktiv">Inaktive</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

How it looks when it wraps now:
[image]

How i want it to look when it wraps:
[image]

How can i make this happen? I tried tweaking flex-wrap, direction, flow etc. Couldn't make it work how i wanted it to.

EDIT: I want it to look like it does in the snippet by default(labels are lined up horizontally). I just want it to wrap with the first label its own line and the two other labels below when the window shrinks.

Comment: width:100% to that item and enable wrap on flex container

Comment: Side note, you don't need `< ...wrap >` technique in flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.  thank you

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

label {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  color: White;
  background: dimgrey;
  
  &:hover {
    color: White;
    background: dimgrey;
  }
}

input[type=radio] + label:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

label + input[type=radio] + label {
  border-left: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.radio-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: max-content;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 0.5px solid dimgrey;
}

.radio-group.flexbox > label:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc( 100% - 12px ) !IMPORTANT;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="radio-group flexbox">
    <input type="radio" id="alle" value="alle" name="selector" checked><label for="alle">Alle</label
    ><input type="radio" id="aktiv" value="aktiv" name="selector" ><label for="aktiv">Aktive</label
    ><input type="radio" id="inaktiv" value="inaktiv" name="selector"><label for="inaktiv">Inaktive</label>
  </div>
</form>
```